# flot.js : Cannot read property 'p2c' of undefined at Plot.plot.pointOffset

Tags: jquery, flot

Using flot.js v 0.83 I have a problem to get data from **.pointOffset**.
This is my code:

```
var position = 0;
var existing = $("#placeholder"+tnr).data("plot");
var leftoffset = existing.offset();
// i receive values for offset!
var lastDatapoint;
$.each(existing.getData(), function(i, item, array) {
            // get the last data point in the series data, e.g. [0, 5]
            lastDatapoint = item.data[item.data.length - 1]; // still receive data here!
            // get the position of the datapoint fails!!!
            position = existing.pointOffset({
              x: lastDatapoint[0],
              y: lastDatapoint[1]
            });
        });
```

Actually i receive values for existing.offset and even for lastDatapoint. But when requesting *pointOffset* i get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'p2c' of undefined
>       at Plot.plot.pointOffset (jquery.flot.min.js:7)

What is wrong here?

Comment: Please show the rest of your code, especially the axes options of your Flot chart. The `pointOffset()` function works with normal options: https://jsfiddle.net/gp760m61/

Comment: @Raidri you are right as log as you assing the plot to a var as in your fiddle `var plot =`. I can't do this, cause i load multiple plots dynamically. Tahts why i am requesting the plot this way: `var existing = $("#placeholder"+tnr).data("plot");`

Comment: The `var plot = ...` is not used, That is not the problem or difference.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, for me it is solved. Due to i need the left Position and width of plot, to align another canvas below, i'll do it this way now:

```
var existing = $("#placeholder"+tnr).data("plot");
// get the left margin
var offset = existing.offset();
var left = offset['left'];
// get width of 'real' plot
var width = existing.width();
```